# Bug? <textarea> automatically adding line break

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to simulate a mini wikipedia and one of its functions is to allow the user to edit a page, for that, I am using markdown and converting to HTML, then get user's input and save it as markdown file. The problem is that whenever the page is edited, its add line break automatically. I am probably missing something. Where is my logic fault?

Here the page display the HTML for whatever content. Another page -> Edit

get_entry() converts markdown to HTML

```
<form action="edit" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{ title }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Edit Page">               
</form>
```

```
def edit(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        title = request.GET.get("title")
        text = util.get_entry(title)

        return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
            "title": title,
            "text": text
        })
```

And here the save process. Edit -> Edit

```
<form action="edit" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{ title }}">
    <textarea name="text" rows="10" cols="20" wrap="hard">{{ text }}</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

```
def save_entry(title, content):
    """
    Saves an encyclopedia entry, given its title and Markdown
    content. If an existing entry with the same title already exists,
    it is replaced.
    """
    filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        default_storage.delete(filename)
    default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))


elif request.method == "POST":
    title = request.POST.get("title")
    text = request.POST.get("text")
    util.save_entry(title, text)
    return redirect(f"/{title}")
```

What happens:
[image: What happens]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Why are you converting markdown to HTML?  You want the user to be editing the markdown, not the converted HTML.  Right?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes. It is only converted to HTML to display. While in edit mode, it have markdown format

Comment: I just wrote a Flask app to test this and cannot duplicate the problem.  You have to be manipulating the text in some way.  You didn't show us `get_entry`; I suspect the problem is there.